# Ubuntu has locked , showings password is incorrect

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, keyboard, password

I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I tried to boot my pc via command line because it doesn’t boot up normally. I wrote this commands in terminal

“sudo systemctl set default-multiuser.target”

then I typed my password. It show a screen where need to log in in any directory , I type grub. Then it required my password, I type my password several times but it always show “ incorrect password “ Now what to do . Please help me.

Comment: It's a little difficult to decode your question, but it *sounds* like you are typing `grub` at the CLI `login: ` prompt? You need to type your linux *username*.

Answer (score -1):

Type as slowly and as simply as possible, making sure you do not typo. Also, you may have forgotten your password. If so, retry with other passwords. If your PC can't boot normally, try reinstalling Ubuntu to use other recovery tools.